# what to call a person with an obsession with eyes

Tags: meaning

[image]
I don't know guys but in have a HUGE. obsession with eyes and its like I don't know but I have a book with 80 sheets of A3 paper and they ALL have eyes on them my phone I full of pictures with eyes my family and friends call me freaks for my birthday I asked my parents for an eye in a jar, obvs they said no, I study my friends and sisters eyes cause she has hetrochromia which is two different colours in the same eye. Don't know somebody. Just gimme something to call this

Comment: Sounds like this site might interest you: https://www.eyedolatryblog.com/2014/08/an-eye-obsession.html

Comment: OMG this helped me so much thank you alot I've looked everywhere and this. Has truly helped me thank you so much ur the best

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *ommatophilia*, or even *ommatomania*, from Greek *omma*. Its converse, *ommatophobia* or *ommetophobia*, is a [recognized anxiety disorder](https://behavenet.com/ommetaphobia).

Comment: Thank you stoneyB that sounds like it makes sense